# How to use sass function as variable value

Tags: html, css, sass

```
@function torem($pixel){
    @return $pixel / 16 / 1px * 1rem;
}

$navHeight: torem(100px);
```

to rem is a function that i'm using to convert pixels into rems but $navHeight gets set to "torem(100px)" as string
something like this,

```
nav{
    height: $navHeight;
}
```

outputs

```
nav{
    height: torem(100px);
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. It's working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: are you setting the function as value for variable

Comment: Tried both variants. As direct value and as variable. Both work.

Comment: could you try keeping function and variable in separate files

Comment: works fine, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you get I assume you declared the function after you are calling it. Move the function to the top of you file and it should work just fine otherwise it will - as you showed in your question - only return the value as a string.

**This works:**

```
@function torem($pixel) {
  @return $pixel / 16 / 1px * 1rem;
}

nav {
  height: torem(120px);
}
```

**This does not:**

```
nav {
  height: torem(120px);
}

@function torem($pixel) {
  @return $pixel / 16 / 1px * 1rem;
}
```

and will return `height: torem(120px);`

PS: It's not very nice to delete a question after it has been answered since people put effort into their answers.

Comment: sorry man,
should not have deleted it,
about the question: of course i declared the function first,
it didn't work because it was it another file and i used @use 
but didn't namespace the function when using it

Comment: Ah alright. Consider answering your own question then ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer